# fread e fseek em c

Tags: c

Escreva um programa usando fwrite e fread que pergunte ao usuário o tipo de lista de compras ele deseja criar: Padaria ou Churrasco.
O programa deve gravar os itens em um arquivo texto até o usuário digitar 0 (zero), ficando da seguinte maneira, por exemplo:

PADARIA      CHURRASCO

pão           carvão

manteiga     picanha

café        refrigerante

....        ....

Obs: Desenvolva um programa que leia o conteúdo do arquivo ao contrário, para isso utilize o fread() e fseek.

Minha dúvida está em como usar o fread e fseek neste caso.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (){
    char nomePad[50], nomeChu[50];
    nomePad[0] = '\0', nomeChu[0] = '\0';
    int x = 0, op;
    FILE *lista;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    printf ("Digite uma opção: \n");
    printf ("\n1 - Padaria;\n");
    printf ("2 - Churrasco.\n");
    scanf ("%d", &op);
    if ((lista = fopen("lista.bin", "wb")) == NULL){
        printf ("Erro no arquivo.\n");
    }
    else {
        if (op == 1){
            fprintf (lista, "\nPADARIA\n\n");
            while (nomePad[x] != '0'){
                printf ("Digite o item: ");
                scanf ("%s[^\n]", nomePad);
                setbuf(stdin, 0);
                fwrite (nomePad[x], sizeof(nomePad), x, lista);
            }
        }
        else{
            fprintf (lista, "\nCHURRASCO\n\n");
            while (nomeChu[x] != '0'){
                printf ("Digite o item: ");
                scanf ("%s[^\n]", nomeChu);
                setbuf(stdin, 0);
                fwrite (&nomeChu[x], sizeof(char), x, lista);
            }
        }
        fclose (lista);
    }
    if ((lista = fopen("lista.bin", "rb")) == NULL){
        printf ("Erro no arquivo.\n");
    }
    else {
        fseek(lista, 0, SEEK_END);
        fread(&nomeChu[x], sizeof(char), 50, lista);
        fread(nomePad[x], sizeof(nomePad), x, lista);
        printf("%s\n%s\n", nomePad, nomeChu);
        fclose(lista);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não misture fprint com fwrite. Lembre-se de que fread() e fwrite() servem para trabalhar com arquivos que contenham blocos de dados de tamanho definido.Você também está confundindo uma string com um caractere em uma dada posição da string.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda 